# cant load or show paddle in javascript canvas (need movement)

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to load a paddle with mouse controls (on the x) when i run and check the console it says "error document.documentElement is not a function"....
Now i have tried to figure it out but i still have no acvaile i am using a udemy course but it was not very helpful im trying to make a paddle with collisions and a ball bouncing with lots of weird elements some are to long that i cant even say them lol

```
<html>

 <body>
     <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  </body>
    <script>
   var ballX = 100
      var ballspeedX = 5
 var ballY = 100
 var ballspeedY = 5

 const PADDLE_WIDTH = 100
 const PADDLE_THICKNESS = 10
   var paddleX = -100

   var canvas
   var canvasContext

function updateMousePos(evt) {

   var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
     var root = document.documentElement();

    var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft
      paddleX = mouseX

    }

    window.onload = function() {

       canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas")
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d")

        var fps = 30

    setInterval(updateAll, 100)


  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePos)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When defining the root var you need to remove the parenthesis from document.documentElement;

Comment: What does the error say? Still the same error message?

Answer (score 0):

btw (this was probably you forgeiting to copy in the end of the thing but) you forgot `</script>` and `</html>` at the end